# how add test data to my local sqlite in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need to add rows of test data to my sqlite.

```
INSERT INTO courses (`name`) VALUES
(‘java'),
(‘ruby').......
```

How can i do it with rails3?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the insert in activerecord way in `db/seeds.rb` something like:

```
courses = Course.create([{ :name => 'java' }, { :name => 'ruby' }])
```

then run `rake db:seed`.

Answer (score 1):

[Fixtures](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures) and [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) are two popular options for adding test data. I'm personally a bigger fan of FactoryGirl because you are working directly with the models in your tests, but it's really a matter of opinion. From my experience, people who use Test::Unit *tend* to be fans of fixtures, and those who use RSpec *tend* to like FactoryGirl. This isn't a hard rule though and you will definitely find people who mix them up. It seems to depend on whether you like using DSLs or plain Ruby in your tests.

Comment: why not just put in db/seeds.rb like mask8 say?

Comment: db/seeds.rb was not intended for automated tests, it is for seeding your development, staging, or production database. It was introduced as an [alternative to adding data with migrations](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/4932f7b38f72104819022abca0c952ba6f9888cb). I strongly urge you to follow Rails conventions and either use fixtures or factories for test data.

Comment: @Yosef I think this is the right way to insert TEST data. I always do test with Fixture actually. Seeds is to provide data that your system requires in order to function. Sorry I just saw your INSERT query and thought that's kind of seeds

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'Factory_girl' for creating test objects in your database.
Just install gem and create Factory objects for your project.
[this is the link about it](http://rubygems.org/gems/factory_girl)